# ScrollView how to scroll to bottom of another view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How can I scroll a LinearLayout in a ScrollView to the bottom of Another View?

I have a calendar imageview at the top of my view.  Underneath there is a ScrollView that contain a list of events for that month.  The ScrollView contains several LinearLayouts that detail the events for that month.  When the user selects an event by touching a button in the linear layout I would like to re-position the current linearlayout to the top of the scrollview, how can I accomplish this?

Below is a brief snippet of what my layout looks like for brevity.

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/cirLinLayContainer"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:background="@drawable/bg_calendar">
                <RelativeLayout> 
                <Button             
                    android:id="@+id/calLeft"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_arrowleft_dwn"/>
                <Button             
                    android:id="@+id/calRight"
                    android:background="@drawable/cal_rightnav_button"/>

                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/cal_september" 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.demo.android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/septemberCalendarScroller">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sepEventLayout01"/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sepEventLayout02"/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sepEventLayout03"/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sepEventLayout04"/>
       </ScrollView>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could measure the height of your linearlayout elements and than use ScrollView.scrollTo() to position the scroll view accordingly.

Comment: How would the width of the LinearLayout give me the position?  Can you give an example of what you suggest?

Comment: Sorry i meant height. Corrected the answer.